# Rollback is not working in liquibase changeset

Tags: database, liquibase, rollback

I use these scripts to make a rollback test. But nothing happens to my database, rollback doesn't work. It still makes an inserting. Please help me!

```
<changeSet author="me" id="123123">
    <sql>
        INSERT INTO employee (id, name) VALUES ('adad', 'test')
    </sql>
    <rollback/>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to understand the concept of rollback when you are working with liquibase scripts as this can be misused.

**Categories of Liquibase Migrations**

There are two categories of Liquibase operations, resulting in a different generation of a rollback statement:

automatic, where migration can deterministically generate steps required for rolling back
manual, where we need to issue a rollback command because migration instruction cannot be used to identify the statement deterministically
For example, the rollback of a “`create table`” statement would be to “`drop`” the created table. This can be determined without a doubt, and therefore the rollback statement can be autogenerated.

On the other hand, the rollback statement for a “`drop table`” command is not possible to be determined. It is not possible to determine the last state of the table, and therefore the rollback statement can't be autogenerated. These types of migration statements require a manual rollback instructions.

Here is one example for above statement

```
<changeSet id="testRollback" author="stackoverflow">
    <createTable tableName="stackoverflow_turorial">
        <column name="id" type="int"/>
        <column name="heading" type="varchar(36)"/>
        <column name="author" type="varchar(36)"/>
    </createTable>
    <rollback>
        <dropTable tableName="stackoverflow_test"/>
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

So in your case rollback cant remain empty and should be given some statement.

> **Let's correct your code.**

```
 <changeSet author="me" id="123123">
        <sql>INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (id, name) VALUES ('adad', 'test')</sql>
        <rollback>DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID = 'adad'</rollback>   
    </changeSet>
```

We can run the migration using the command:

```
mvn liquibase:update
```

After the executing we can rollback the action using:

```
mvn liquibase:rollback
```

This executes the rollback segment of the changeset and should revert the task completed during the update stage. But if we issue this command alone, the build will fail.

The reason for that is – we do not specify the limit of rollback; the database will be completely wiped out by rolling back to the initial stage. Therefore it's mandatory to define one of the three constraints below to limit the rollback operation when the condition is satisfied:

1. rollbackTag
2. rollbackCount
3. rollbackDate

   **Rolling Back to a Tag**

We can define a particular state of our database to be a tag. Therefore, we can reference back to that state. Rolling back to the tag name “1.0” looks like:

```
mvn liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackTag=1.0
```

This executes rollback statements of all the changesets executed after tag “1.0”.

**Rolling Back by Count**

Here, we define how many changesets we need to be rolled back. If we define it to be one, the last changeset execute will be rolled back:

```
mvn liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackCount=1
```

**Rolling Back to Date**

We can set a rollback target as a date, therefore, any changeset executed after that day will be rolled back:

```
mvn liquibase:rollback "-Dliquibase.rollbackDate=Jun 03, 2017"
```

The date format has to be an ISO data format or should match the value of DateFormat.getDateInstance() of the executing platform.

Also you can mention the sql in different sql file and can give the reference here.